# Overlay graph on grid

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to translate the following picture into LaTeX
[image: P]

Here is what I did by writing these codes:

```
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=grid]
    \draw[cyan!25,ultra thick] (-2,-2) grid (7,6);
    \draw[step=5mm,cyan!25,thick] (-2,-2) grid (7,6);
    \draw[step=1mm,cyan!25,very thin] (-2,-2) grid (7,6);
    \draw[-latex,thick] (-2,0)--(7.4,0) node[right] {\footnotesize $(1)$};
    \draw[-latex,thick] (0,-2)--(0,6.4) node[above] {\footnotesize $(2)$};
    \draw[-,thick] (-0.2,1) node[anchor=east]{1} --(0.2,1);
    \draw[-,thick] (1,-0.2) node[anchor=north]{1} --(1,0.2);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(grid.center)}]
    \begin{axis}[
        %grid = major,
        axis lines=none,
        ticks=none
        ]
        \addplot [domain=-1:5,smooth, ultra thick, black!20!red] {0.5*x^2-3*x+2.5};
    \end{axis}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The graph is not in the right place. The "axis" of the second scope should coincide with the "axis" of the first scope i.e. the point (0,0) in their coordinate system should be the same. I somehow do not know how to do that as I am still learning tikz.

BTW: If there is an simpler solution where you do not need to overlay two stuff, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much easier to draw everything that should be scaled or aligned relative to the `axis` environment *inside* this environment:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=none,
    ticks=none,
    x=1cm,
    y=1cm,
    clip=false
    ]
    \draw[cyan!25, ultra thick] (-2,-2) grid (7,6);
    \draw[step=5mm, cyan!25, thick] (-2,-2) grid (7,6);
    \draw[step=1mm, cyan!25, very thin] (-2,-2) grid (7,6);
    \draw[-latex, thick] (-2,0) -- (7.4,0) node[right] {\footnotesize $(1)$};
    \draw[-latex, thick] (0,-2) -- (0,6.4) node[above] {\footnotesize $(2)$};
    \draw[thick] (-0.2,1) node[anchor=east] {1} -- (0.2,1);
    \draw[thick] (1,-0.2) node[anchor=north] {1} -- (1,0.2);

    \addplot[domain=-1:5, smooth, ultra thick, black!20!red] {0.5*x^2-3*x+2.5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's much better. New things to learn! I've one question to your enviroment, how do you "rescale" the size of the tikzpicture, like 1.5 times bigger than the original one?

Comment: @UnknownW Just `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]`. This will scale the coordinate system. So, font size and line width will stay the same.

Comment: Lol, before I asked you, I actually wrote "scale = 1.5" within axis enviroment without noticing where I put it. It enlarged distance between the ticks in the axes, so I thought something was wrong. Thanks for helping!